# Use properties of external property file when property file is not present after loading

Tags: java, spring

I am accessing external property file as below in my spring application. This file contains sensitive data - some deryption keys needed by the application.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${JBOSS_HOME}/123.properties,classpath:constants.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>

<bean id="helloWorldBean"
    class="com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.services.HelloWorld">
    <property name="key1" value="${key1}" />
    <property name="key2" value="${key2}" />
     <property name="key3" value="${key3}" />
</bean>
```

Once the application is started up the property file will be deleted by a external service for security purpose.

As the property file is not availabe after couple of minutes, how to access the keys once it is deleted?

As the keys are fixed, can I assign the values to a `Singleton` class which holds `key1,key2,key3` and use the `singleton` object?

Will this be the recommended solution?

Comment: What happens when you need to restart the application?

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid possible issues with file deleted before it has been read, I would also add some logic that confirms all keys are read and ready to be used. When this check passed, some state should be updated, indicating that file can be deleted. The external service which deletes the file should act like

- Do check whether file is read;
- If no, sleep for some time;
- Go to first point if previous is true (file not read yet);
- If yes, delete file and stop activities;